# Rails nested form attribute uniqueness validation

Tags: validation, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms

I have 3 nested models

- Course

  - Company

    - Student

I have an attribute called 'student_number' in Student model. I want make it unique relative to Course (1st parent). Means, duplicate student_numbers will not be allowed per a single course.

I have written following one -

validates :student_number, presence: true, numericality: { only_integer: true }, uniqueness: { scope: :company_id }

But it is working only for Company (2nd parent), in this also validation not working if 2 students are added at the same time.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

```
#app/models/student.rb

...

validates :student_number, presence: true, numericality: { only_integer: true }, uniqueness: { scope: :course_id }


def course_id
  company.course.id
end
```

Of course, this will perform a look-up for each course.id so won't be very performant on big systems.

You could reorganise the database structure so students are directly under courses if that makes more sense, with company as a different parent. Or you could put a cache of the course id on the student table if things slow down.

Alternatively you could write a custom validator if you can make it more performant:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods